# How to bring NSDecimalNumber from core data to label with 2 digits after , or . even if the value is round

Tags: ios, ios9, nsdecimalnumber, swift2

In my CoreData Base is a value 12500.00, it is stored as 12500.

I want to bring it in a tableview label and I would like to have a number with 2 digits like currency.

```
var unit = "€"    
textLabel.text = ("%@ %.2f" ,unit, (entityName[indexPath.row].price!))`
```

I do get only the Numbers with decimal like € 12500,55 in my label, but not € 12500,00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let currency = "€"
let costAsString = String(format: "\(currency) %.2f", Double(12500))
print(costAsString) // € 12500.00
```

Comment: yes that works. how would you localized the text like 12.500,00 or 12,500.00 ?

Comment: you can extend your values to conform to CustomDebugStringConvertible protocol.

Comment: when I try this code it doesn't work : `String(format: "%@ %.2f", arguments: unitSymbole,  [Double(12500)])` unitSymbole is set as String to  var  to "€"

Answer (score 0):

I would use `NSNumberFormatter`:

```
 NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];                
 numberFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle;
 NSString *currencyString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber: price];
```

(Sorry, code is in `ObjectiveC`)